# django translation doesn't work although dgango_language cookie is set

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

It's been 3 days and I'm getting tired of this.
Here's my setting file:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-z$__b9aa(_3!czi7ssop9cr2lae^9)f^!_kq+y_n=+6u=ul!%q"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mainapp",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "soroushprojects.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": ['templates'],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "soroushprojects.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LAGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
)

LOCALE_PTHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['static']

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

as you can see I tried adding "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware" to MIDDLEWARE and "django.template.context_processors.i18n" to content processors.

The urls:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', views.SendMessage.as_view()),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('articles/<int:id>/', views.ShowArticlesView.as_view()),
    path('articles/', views.ArticlesListView.as_view()),
    path('projects/<int:id>/', views.ShowProjectView.as_view()),
    path('projects/', views.ProjectsListView.as_view()),
    path('i18n/',include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('', views.home),
]
```

Views:

```py
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

locale files:

```
locale/
      en/
         LC_MASSAGES/
                    django.mo
                    django.po
      fa/
        LC_MESSAGES/
                   django.po
                   django.mo
```

fa/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-12-07 00:03+0330\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

#: .\soroushprojects\settings.py:112
msgid "English"
msgstr "الگلیسی"

#: .\soroushprojects\settings.py:113
msgid "Persian"
msgstr "فارسی"

#: .\templates\home.html:6
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "سلام"
```

home.html:

```html
{% load i18n %}
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="language" type="hidden" value="fa"/>
    <input type="submit" value="change"/>
</form>
{% trans "Hello" %}
```

when i check my browser cookies djngo_language is set to 'fa' but it doesn't translate the word "Hello" to "سلام":
[Browser cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC3Qg.jpg)

I tried `manage.py makemessages --all` and `manage.py compilemessages` hundreds of times. I Tried Every solution that I found on the Internet but none of them worked. Then I deleted my project and moved all its codes to a new project, but that also didn't work. I even tried reinstalling gettext many times in different ways.I also tried using {% blocktrans %}{% endblocktrans %} instead of trans tag. I'm just getting crazy

I expected django to translate "Hello" to "سلام"

Answer (score 1):

As [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) say, `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` should be placed between `"django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware"` and `"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware"`,

> It should come after SessionMiddleware, because LocaleMiddleware makes use of session data. And it should come before CommonMiddleware because CommonMiddleware needs an activated language in order to resolve the requested URL.

So your `MIDDLEWARE` setting should look like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [        
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",        
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",        
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',        
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",        
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",        
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",        
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",        
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware"        
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django do you use? The `trans` HTML template tag seems not in use any more, in [4.x docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag) `translate` is the name of the tag in the examples.

I'd also [check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) too, just in case it has anything to do with the `Accept-Language` HTTP header.

Comment: I tried that, That's not the problem. I even tried translating words in my views but that didn't work. I use django 4.1.3